# How to tell that string is a json?

Tags: python, json

I have a string that I pull from a REST API that is actually a JSON.

I can't use `req.json()` as python doesn't format json correctly i.e. it is using single quotes and not double quotes, plus it puts a unicode symbol where there shouldn't be one.  This means I can't use it to respond back to REST as the JSON is not formatted correctly.

However `r.text` prints json that I could use, if I could just tell python: "this is a json and not a string, take it just as it is and use it as a json".

Is there anyway I could do this? Or is there anyway to tell Python to properly format json object as per json spec (i.e. not have unicode characters, and use double quotes).

EDIT:

Apparently this wasn't clear, I apologize.

The issue is that I have to send back a proper JSON formatted object and NOT python object.  Here is what I get:

r.text:
{"domain":"example.com", "Link":null, "monitor":"true"}

r.json():
{u'domain':u'example.com', u'Link": None, u'minotor':True}

This is NOT proper JSON formating.  You can't have the unicode character, it isn't None it is null, and it isn't True it is true.  You also should have double and not single quotes (not as big deal I think).

Hope this clarifies my issues.

Comment: What is failing to create valid JSON? Have you considered raising a bug? Have you used e.g. `json.dumps`?

Comment: Have you tried using the `json` library? https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: `python doesn't format json correctly`  I would be very surprised. Can you provide source to that affirmation?

Comment: When you say "tell that", do you mean "determine that", or do you mean "tell Python that"? Are you asking how to determine whether a string contains valid JSON text, or are you trying to get Python to treat the string a certain way? The way your title is currently phrased, it's asking how to determine whether a string contains JSON text, which doesn't seem to match what your question body is asking.

Comment: by incorrect json I mean that it has the "unicode" symbol (i.e. u'domain') and single but not double quotes.  In addition it has "True" and None, as oppose to true and null.
All no issues at all with typical python, but in this case I have to put back the response without any of these things in them.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if a string is valid json by catching the error.

```
import json

def is_json(myjson):
  try:
    json_object = json.loads(myjson)
  except ValueError, e:
    return False
  return True
```

Test cases:

```
print is_json("{}")                          #prints True
print is_json("{asdf}")                      #prints False
print is_json('{ "age":100}')                #prints True
print is_json("{'age':100 }")                #prints False
print is_json("{\"age\":100 }")              #prints True
print is_json('{"age":100 }')                #prints True
print is_json('{"foo":[5,6.8],"foo":"bar"}') #prints True
```

Comment: "except ValueError, e:" is now "except ValueError as e"  in python3

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
request_as_json = json.loads(r.text)
```

Then you can call things like `request_as_json['key']`

["More Info Here"](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads)

Comment: issue I have with json.loads is that it puts unicode characters, single quotes, as well as True, and None (as opposed to true and null) this is what is creating my issue.

if I do json.dumps it escapes all double quotes like this '\\"domain\\"'

Comment: This only exists when your are printing it to screen right. treat it as json and it will behave as jason because it is json. Internally those things may as welll not be there.

`>>> x = json.loads('{"hello": 9}')

>>> x

{u'hello': 9}

>>> x['hello']

9

>>>`

When you are ready to get your work back to you in proper json then its time to `>>> json.dumps(x)
'{"hello": 9}'`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the data in the JSON message, `req.json()` already does what you need. It parses the JSON message into a Python data structure, generally some nested format of lists and dicts. The result doesn't look like valid JSON text because it's not JSON any more; it's a data structure you can actually index and get data out of.

If you need a JSON string - a sequence of characters with braces and colons and double-quotation marks - perhaps because you're planning to send it over the network again, `req.text` is what you need.

Comment: Completely agree with everything you said.  However the issue with req.text is that it is a unicode object and I actually do need json object.  What I think I need to do is to import via json manipulate it and then send it back on the wire with proper json.   It is the last step that is killing me, and for which I haven't found solution yet.

Comment: @JacekPerry: Hold on. What do you think a "json object" is? At least by the JSON standard, a JSON object is text, specifically a JSON string that would be parsed to a dict by Python. It's what you would get from `req.text`. If you need to send this over a network connection, you may need the string to be encoded to bytes in some particular encoding, in which case you might need `req.content` or `req.text.encode('whateverencoding')`.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  From python perspective json object is in fact dictionary (typically multi level dictionary and list).  However one must send back this object as standard JSON, and therein lies my issue.  I can parse r.text as a dictionary (or just use r.json()) but I need to return the object back as a JSON object (or as you point out a string) properly.

Comment: @JacekPerry: Ignore the fact that this text is JSON. Make no attempt to parse it as JSON. Use no tools with JSON in the name. What problem do you encounter if you just read the text from the response and send that text over the wire to whoever needs to receive it?

Comment: The issue is that I have to manipulate it, add/remove/modify.  This makes things difficult if it isn't parsable object.

Comment: @JacekPerry: Parse it to a dict with `req.json()`, modify the dict however you want, then serialize the dict to a JSON string with `json.dumps(your_modified_dict)`.